# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{a}{n})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm very new to the epsilon definition of a limit and I was hoping I could get some feedback to see if I have the right idea.

For any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)=0$$

**Proof:**

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $N>\frac{|a|}{\epsilon}$. Then for all $n\geq N$, since $n\geq N>\frac{|a|}{\epsilon}$, we have

$$n>\frac{|a|}{\epsilon}\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;\epsilon >\frac{|a|}{n}$$

Therefore,

$$\left|\frac{a}{n}-0\right|=\frac{|a|}{n}<\epsilon$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Use the Archimedean property

Comment: @xXACEXx I am when I choose $N>\frac{|a|}{\epsilon}$, aren't I?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: yep looks good to me, I would've stated $\left|\frac{\alpha}{n}\right|=\frac{|\alpha|}{n}\leq\frac{|\alpha|}{N}<\varepsilon$

Comment: Can you prove for $n\to-\infty$ as well?

Comment: Looks all fine to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is $100\%$ correct. One can generalize your theorem for a sequence $\displaystyle\sigma_{n}=\frac{\alpha}{n^{r}}$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ as follow :

Let $\varepsilon>0$, then by the archimedean property, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{N}<\sqrt[r]{\varepsilon}$. Now we show that starting this index $N$, elements of $\sigma_{n}$ are in the neighborhood of $0$. For $n\geq N$, we have that :
$$
\left|\frac{\alpha}{n^{r}}\right|=\frac{|\alpha|}{n^{r}}\leq\frac{|\alpha|}{N^{r}}<\varepsilon
$$
which means that $|\sigma_{n}|<\varepsilon\implies\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma_{n}=0$

Comment: $r\geq0$ right?

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it clear that $r>0$. Thank you